# Cassandra Recently Blue Screen Led to corrupt SSTables

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

Up to this point all was well.  We had a BSOD on a machine and now have corrupt SSTables.  We are trying to find the correct procedure to get this node online.  I would just love to kill the data and repair the node as we have replication 2 but I cant do that due to the amount of data on each node.

Attached is the error.

I tried to run nodetool scrub but since DSE cannot start, I get the normal cannot connect to 127.0.0.1 error.

Should I edit the config and change from policy stop to best effort then start/run the command?

Thanks,

---

ERROR 20:58:34  Exiting forcefully due to file system exception on startup, disk failure policy "stop"
org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.(CompressionMetadata.java:131) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.create(CompressionMetadata.java:85) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedSegmentedFile$Builder.metadata(CompressedSegmentedFile.java:79) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile$Builder.complete(CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.java:72) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Builder.complete(SegmentedFile.java:169) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:741) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:692) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:480) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:376) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$4.run(SSTableReader.java:523) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.(CompressionMetadata.java:106) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
ERROR 20:58:34  Exiting forcefully due to file system exception on startup, disk failure policy "stop"
org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.(CompressionMetadata.java:131) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.create(CompressionMetadata.java:85) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedSegmentedFile$Builder.metadata(CompressedSegmentedFile.java:79) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile$Builder.complete(CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.java:72) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SegmentedFile$Builder.complete(SegmentedFile.java:169) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:741) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:692) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:480) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:376) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$4.run(SSTableReader.java:523) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.(CompressionMetadata.java:106) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
INFO  20:58:34  DSE shutting down...
INFO  20:58:34  All plugins are stopped.

Comment: have you tried the offline scrub tool? https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTableScrub_t.html

Comment: Yes, I started it but then quickly stopped due to the #1 rule.  Try scrub first.  Should I try this one instead?

Comment: that or just delete the corrupted sstable and do a repair

Comment: If you do delete the sstable run a repair after you're up. BTW this is windows?

Comment: Sorry, no.  Its Ubuntu 14.04, but I copied from WinSCP (Connecting to the console).  Will the repair require to go through all data?  Will the node come up and accept new data while it does the repair?  Before I say my next statement, Yes, I know its not what normal people do.  We have about 14TB on this node.  I even already spoke with DataStax and had a meeting about what we are doing. Will it have to transfer the 14TB back or just verify the data from the other nodes?  Does it even need other nodes to re-create the SSTables?

Comment: Just finished running the Scrub.  Came back and wouldnt boot.  I changed config to best_Efforts and now running a repair on that specific node under that range.  :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if some disk failure caused the SSTables to get corrupted? That is one of the main reason for stable corruption. If it is the case repair the disk and then run nodetool repair.

Comment: I dont think the issue was related to a drive failure, as I can read all the data on the drive.  I think it was in the middle of a write, the BSOD happened due to a failing RAID card and thus caused corruption.  I am running currently sscrub for the last 4 days, still waiting for it to complete.

Comment: what was the result of the nodetool scrub, was it useful?

Answer (score 0):

Modify cassandra policy in cassandra.yaml on failed nodes.

1) disk failure policy to best_effort
2) Start DSE start or (Cassandra service)
3) nodetool scrub